# CGI includes not working after migration to new server.

Tags: nginx, cgi, selinux

I have a couple applications (PDG Stores) running on a Plesk server running Apache both of them use a CGI include to run a php script that builds their menus.  Upon moving to a new server Plesk12 Odin + Nginx + Apache  none of these includes work any longer.

Not sure where to start here, is it Nginx, Apache? or SeLinux?

- there are no errors in any logs at all, includes fail silently.
- the Apache include module is enabled

Not sure how to troubleshoot for Nginx or SeLinux

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Can you check the error messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and the `/var/log/httpd/suexec_log` ?

Comment: mmm there is no audit.log and all there is in the su_exec log are a lot of gid: (1004/1004) cmd: commerce.cgi & gid: (1004/1004) cmd: cgi_wrapper